# How to find the duck race in Shenmue II?

Tags: shenmue-2

In [Yu Suzuki’s IAmA on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/3ahcwf/i_am_yu_suzuki_new_posting/), [someone asked](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/3ahcwf/i_am_yu_suzuki_new_posting/cscnv0v) him:

> Can we expect more duck racing in Shenmue III? That was the best easter egg I've ever seen in a video game.

According to a video uploaded by the Shenmue Dojo, it’s part of *Shenmue II*:

**How can I find this duck race?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have fulfilled the prerequisites, you can go to the Duck Race by speaking to **Izumi Takano** in the **Tomato Convenience Store**. You can find the store in the **Golden Qr.** of **Wan Chai**.

### Prerequisites

You’ve to be on disc 2 (for the Dreamcast version).

You need these items:

1. Big Bronze Medal
2. Big Silver Medal

(**tl;dr**: [This gameplay video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rO9RaWimKUk) shows Ryo getting the two medals, choosing the "A Vacant Lot" variant to get the Big Bronze Medal.)

#### How to get the Big Bronze Medal?

Talk to both:

- **Izumi Takano** (see above for her location)
- **Eileen M. Edelweiss** (she trains at the **Pigeon Park** in **Worker’s Pier**, **Aberdeen**)

Now there are three possible ways:

- Find it!

  You can find it on the table in **A Vacant Lot**, which is located in the **Green Market Qr.** of **Wan Chai**. ([This gameplay video shows it, from minute 6:20 on.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rO9RaWimKUk))
- Buy it!

  Pay the waitress from the restaurant **Lai Lai Eatery** (in **Aberdeen**)  for the trouble you have caused when chasing Wong.
- Win it!

  In the **Lucky Charm Qr.** of **Wan Chai**, there is a **Roll it on Top** stand from **Zhiqing Shi** (next to the Prophecy Fortuneteller’s). Win 5 times in a row. ([This gameplay video shows it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPgOYLiMlQ0))

#### How to get the Big Silver Medal?

The Big Bronze Medal allows you to access the third floor of the **Pine Game Arcade**. It’s located in the **Golden Qr.** of **Wan Chai**.

Enter the third floor, select "Entry" (not "Watch") and defeat **Eileen M. Edelweiss**.

Then enter the third floor again and defeat **Izumi Takano**.

---

References: [Duck Racing (Neoseeker Shenmue Wiki)](http://shenmue.neoseeker.com/wiki/Duck_Racing) · [The Duck Races (Wikia Shenmue Wiki](http://shenmue.wikia.com/wiki/The_Duck_Races)

---

#### Bonus: There’s also a Big Gold Medal …

To get the Big Gold Medal, you have to win the Duck Race with [your own duck](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/224641/30863).